Selenium - Unable to find element using xpath
I am writing a webscraper in python to get the current patch version for a list of products. I am trying to locate the text by XPATH, but I am being told that no such element exists. I have tried both an implicit and explicit wait up to 60 seconds, but still have not had any success. I see that there is an iframe on the page, but the text I am trying to access is not in that iframe, so I don't think it's relevant. Either way, I tried to switch to that iframe and find the element in there as a test, but was not successful.
This is the page I am trying to scrape
I am simply trying to get the newest version number.
I have the XPATH as: /html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/span[1]
This is the code I am using
     url = "https://compatibility.rockwellautomation.com/Pages/ProductReplacement.aspx?crumb=101&restore=1&vid=53216"
        RA_XPATH = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/span[1]"
        driver.get(url)
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, RA_XPATH)))
        version = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, RA_XPATH)

I am able to locate it with the Rel XPath, but I would like to use the Abs XPath because it looks like it is the same across multiple products. For Example on this page, the Abs XPath is the same as the other page, but the Rel Xpath is different
I am completely stumped.
I am relatively new to all of this, so I thank you for your patience!

XPaths are now a headache, use CSS selectors instead which is faster to code and better looking, refer to the official locating elements in Selenium tutorial.

As Conal said,  XPath expressions generated by the browser using the Developer Tools (F12) are not best nor optimal. You can try these as a last resource for your project. Using an Xpath expression generated on your own it will benefit your code to have a better maintainability.
As the DOM structure (HTML tree-like code for the page) is subject to frequent changes in the future, having optimal Xpath (based on Text, Objects or Classes Names) will withstand your code to future changes.  Using XPath expressions generated by the browser, will result in that your Xpath predicate will stop working.
In regards what Xpath expression for your page. You can use this one:
//span[contains(@class,"currentVersion")]
Check this screenshot to get more details:

Try to learn more about Xpath, here there are 2 resources:
https://intellipaat.com/blog/xpath-in-selenium
https://fifithecat.medium.com/xpath-example-73bf66c2377c

Of course, a CSS selector "span.currentVersion", would be even better.

You could use a different form of XPATH or a CSS selector as follows:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=true")
url = "https://compatibility.rockwellautomation.com/Pages/ProductReplacement.aspx?crumb=101&restore=1&vid=53216"

xpath = """//*[@id="TableHeader"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span"""
css = "span.currentVersion"

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    for selector in (By.XPATH, xpath), (By.CSS_SELECTOR, css):
        span = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(selector))
        print(span.get_attribute("textContent"))

Output:
6.008
6.008


I would not use a browser-generated XPath such as:
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/span[1]

An XPath expression like that is excessively long and hard to read because  you can only understand it by tediously tracing your way from the root html element right down to the actual point of interest.
NB that path expression depends on details of the page that are not directly relevant; i.e. you don't really care about the div structure of the page as such. Note that the authors of the page could invalidate your path expression by adding or subtracting a div at some point, and your current path could end up pointing either to nothing, or (worse!) to some other element.
I'd say it's generally better to write an XPath expression yourself which focuses on some meaningful features of the element you want to retrieve.
What's directly relevant is the text 'Version', and my choice would probably be to write an XPath that finds that text, and navigates from there to the following table cell.
//td[text()[contains(., 'Version')]]/following-sibling::td[1]/span

i.e. the span within the td which immediately follows the td which contains the text 'Version'.
Alternatively, a query which retrieves the span based on its title attribute might be better:
//span[@title='Preferred']

